# How to log "model time elapsed" in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

How to log the amount of time elapsed with respect to model runtime, so that when I fast-forward the model run, the time that I print reflect that?
I have tried:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

as well as:

```
time(MINUTE);
```

While the first one captures Systems time, the second one also does not increase proportionally when I increase the run speed.
I am assuming, when I increase the run speed of the model, the model effectively start simulating for future!
For example, when model time unit is in minutes and I increase the model run speed to 50x, it means 1 minutes elapsed in real world means 50 minutes elapsed in model world.

Comment: Do you mean to log the real-world time that elapsed since the model started? Why would you need that, ever? You can visually see that in the developer panel at runtime, if you like. But why would you make it part of your model?

Comment: I dont need real-world time, I need time elapsed in the model world

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `traceln(time())` to get the elapsed model time in the model time units.

To get it in a specific time unit like minutes, call `traceln(time(MINUTE))`.

What do are doing is to call the real-world time from your computer clock, 100% independent of the model time

To understand the difference between virtual model time and real-world time, see the [help](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/model-time.html#model-time-units).

Comment: That is what I tried, but when I speed up the simulation by 25 or 50 times, I dont see the traceln(time()) reflect that. If I speed up the model run by 50 times (my model time unit is in minutes), shouldn't my log reflect time-elapsed as 50 minutes when real-world time elapsed is 1 min?

Comment: No, this is how it works: If you model time unit is minutes, running it at x1 means every real SECOND 1 virtual MINUTE passes. If you speed up by x50, every real SECOND you will see 50 virtual MINUTES pass. This works 100% , I think you misunderstand that it would pass 1 virtual MINUTE each real MINUTE if running at x1. This is not the case!

Comment: Maybe I am logging it in the wrong block, I am logging it in the "Source" block. If I want to see the time elapsed, where should I add the tracel() command?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong. Always know *when* your code is executed. In your case, it depends on which code field in the Source block you used. Why not create a button with the code and you click it at runtime? You will see it working. Then, learn what the different code sections in the blocks actually do and when they are executed. AnyLogic help covers a ton on this. Then, please improve future questions to show more details, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: And finally ,please upvote the reply to show it was correct :) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: I would upvote and accept the answer if it solved my problem, but it does not. Even using the button I don't see the time-elapsed log increasing by 1 minute when in real-world time elapsed is 1 second

Comment: Sure, then either create a new issue with clear details or edit this question to clarify. Happy to help, but please make it easy for us to help you :) We cannot guess what you are actually doing :)